# using qt : How To Build a Gui OnTop Of a Console Application?

Tags: qt, console-application, bison

i have a console application that generated from bison (a parser) and i want to build a simple gui for it
so i can send input from this gui to the console and get output from the console into the gui .
i tried to do that using java process class but it doesnt work for me , please help me to do that 
using qt .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the complexity of the data you want to feed in/out of your console application.

**Low complexity**
Use some command switches that you pass from your Qt GUI to your console application. Look at the [QProcess class documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).

**High complexity**
I would go with an RPC-like solution. Look at the [QtDBus documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html) (Linux/Unix only).

Note: I made the assumption that *you want to keep your generated bison parser apart from your Qt GUI* (in case you need the regenerate it again).

Comment: Command line applications already have "rpc like solutions", they are called stdin & stdout =)

Comment: hahaha, right. :) But it could be a pain to parse if your console application output a lot of info to sdtout. Hence my two fold response : Low vs High complexity. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put the following entries in your `.PRO` file :

```
\# Application template<br>
TEMPLATE = app

\# QMake configuration<br>
CONFIG  += console
```

You can then create a Window in Qt, and you'll have your main window next to a console !

Example :

```
main.cpp
{
    QApplication App(argc, argv);
    ...
    MainFrm* pMainFrm = new MainFrm();
    pMainFrm->show();
    ...
    int ExitCode = App.exec();
    return ExitCode;
}
```

Hope it helps a bit !

Answer (score 1):

Keep your console and your graphical application, two separated applications. You already have the console one, so let's see how to make the other:

Make a normal GUI application in Qt and, using the `QProcess` class, call your console application. Use the [`readData()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qprocess.html#readData) and [`writeData()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qprocess.html#writeData) (and similar) methods of this class to read from standard output and write to standard input of your console application.

Check the [`QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qprocess.html) documentation for details.

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33506-where-is-cout-in-Qt-Creator

first add

```
CONFIG   += console
```

to your .pro file

second use

```
#include <stdio.h>

  QTextStream out(stdout);
  out << QString("Some text");
```

For me it works this way.

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative: Tcl/TK**

Unless you have good reason to use QT you might find it easier to use [Tcl/Tk.](http://www.tcl.tk/)  Tcl was designed from the ground up for wrapping scripting and GUI facilities around existing C programs and is by far the easiest way to do this.  It supports quite a few different ways to integrate C code and Tk (the GUI toolkit shipped with Tcl/Tk) is quite concise to program and very simple to learn (think: one 2 hour lab in a CS paper).

**Tcl integration features:**

- Tcl can open a full-duplex pipe to the program and communicate down the pipe.  At a guess this is probably the best option for you.
- You can use fork/exec to run the program, passing command line arguments.
- You can also embed the Tcl interpreter in your C program; the API for doing this is dead simple.
- Tcl has API's (also quite simple) for extending the interpreter with new commands.
- Probably one or two other ways that I can't remember off the top of my head.