# Building a GUI for a console application using QProcess in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I want to build a GUI on top of ndpiReader application that [comes](https://github.com/sipcapture/nDPI/blob/master/example/ndpiReader.c) with nDPI library. My question is:

1- Is it possible to use Qt's QProcess to create a GUI for this application is written in C and uses a library (nDPI) that is also written in C? This is very important question for my work.

2- I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193554/using-qt-how-to-build-a-gui-ontop-of-a-console-application) question with the same title as mine, but it doesn't specify the steps for a beginner like me how to set up the project in order to kick start. From QProcess documentation [page](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qprocess.html#details) I can see that one can send arguments for the target application through QProcess method `start()` but I'm somehow confused, this is my first time trying to write a GUI for a console application, Do I need to include any part of the target app's source code in my Qt project? What type of project should I choose in Qt Creator when I first create a project? (I personally guess I should use Qt Widget Application, but I need confirmation of that).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ***Do I need to include any part of the target app's source code in my Qt project?*** No. You do not need to include any part of this executable's code in your Qt application.

Comment: ***Is it possible to use Qt's QProcess to create a GUI for this application is written in C and uses a library (nDPI) that is also written in C?*** I would say most likely. I have done similar for applications that I did not have the source code.

Comment: You can use probably ndpireader from a UI application, the question is, why not use ndpi directly which ndpireader is probably just wrapping to make the functionality available to command line. What is easier will also depend on the complexity of your use cases, and if you need interactivity and user feedback etc. beyond what ndpireader provides.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld my goal is to write a GUI for the program ndpireader not really the functionalities that ndpi offers. I'm aware ndpireader is just a demo of all ndpi can offer.